# @param tag alignment in php code sniffer

Tags: php, coding-style, phpcodesniffer

I am using php code sniffer for a function, i want to add @param tag but it is giving me alignment error of first and second param.

```
/**
 * for generating thumbnail 
 *
 * @param int    $minSize    an integer to size of thumbnail
 * @param string $sourceUrl  the string to source url 
 *
 * @return int the integer 
 */

function imgThumbs($minSize, $sourceUrl)
{   
}
```

please suggest, what is the problem why it is not showing , first and second are not aligned.

Comment: `@param` should work fine with `Code_Sniffer`, whats the error exactly.

Comment: 471 | ERROR | The variable names for parameters $minSize (1) and $sourceUrl
     |       | (2) do not align
 471 | ERROR | The comments for parameters $minSize (1) and $sourceUrl (2) do
     |       | not align
 471 | ERROR | Expected 1 space after the longest variable name

Comment: remove the spaces from the variable and the description and relplace theb with tabs for alignment.

Comment: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.sample.php

Comment: @Robert still do not align i m not getting, what i am missing ?

Comment: @Robert i checked the link already and google other article but still not finding

Comment: what happens if you remove the comments leaving the variables.

Comment: it is showing missing comments and other alignment error with name and comments

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Expected **1 space** after the longest variable name

In your code the longest variable name `$sourceUrl` is followed by **2 spaces**.

**Edit:** Here is how it should work (at least *this* error should disappear). I used dots for spaces at the important places.

```
/**
 * for generating thumbnail 
 *
 * @param.int....$minSize...an integer to size of thumbnail
 * @param.string.$sourceUrl.the string to source url 
 *
 * @return int the integer 
 */
```

Comment: its not working ,Please, can you give me format of two variable with written space and tab where to give , and one variable is longer than other ,Please write space don't give actual spaces , Please confirm your understanding